# Creating my small farm by virtual machines to learn scalability issues

Tags: linux, virtualization, load-balancing, scalability, web-farm

I would like to create a fake server farm using virtual machines with Ubuntu server on them. I do not plan to use those as a real farm to host people websites etc.

I recently read about scalability, the ability to add new servers to your website without having to hassle too much with the code. I would like to learn more about this, just out of curiosity, plus I'm planning a website that *might* require such things.

I would like to understand clearly how load balancers work, how a MySql query or http request can be sent to any of hundreds of servers to avoid pressure on a single one.

Even though I own a Core i7, it's clear that as I approach to 4-5 virtual machines things will collapse, so just for fun :)

I know it will not be easy to find a "tutorial on how to build your own server farm". So I'm asking here. Which tools do I require? Where can I find appropriate documentation (please not the unix "man")? Any link that will explain things better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's hard to write down all the info you need. search for some blogs. and at any time focus only one part of the picture. http and mysql are completely separate things, and the solutions for load balancing those are completely different.

Comment: This earned an OT close because of a few things 1) We don't do educational questions here (point 3 under NOT about in the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq)). 2) This is 'in the home' (point 1). 3) isn't in "a professional capacity".

Comment: And just as a general comment to help you maybe better refine your search... how do you expect to learn anything meaningful about scalability by building a tiny cluster of VMs... that don't have enough resources to scale at all anyway?

Answer (score 1):

CPU is not a limiting factor for VMs. RAM is.

In your scenario look at `OpenVZ`. To start with. About load-balancing: look at `LVS`.
If you are talking about application-server-load-balancing - get a proper `tomcat` training.

But what is your actual question?